# Cumulocity plugin subscription

Tags: cumulocity

I would like to know which plugins to subscribe to with my app to be able to have a "Home" tab with the possibility to add widgets on it. So far I tried adding the following:

- SCADA Widget (core)
- Cockpit Home (cockpit)
- Dashboard (cockpit)
- Dashboard (core)

As a result a have a home tab with an add widget button as I wanted, however nothing happens when I click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your list of plugins needed is complete (of course default "Branding: Cumulocity (core)" is also needed). The issue is rather related to other settings of your application.